# Selecting a radio button from a value stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I've found it pretty straightforward to display the value of a variable (active), being passed into my EJS from a route:

```
<!-- Active Text Input-->
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
   <label for="active" class="form-label" >Active</label>
   <input type="text" name="active" id="active" class="form-control" value= "<%= active %>"/>
</div>
```

But because "active" can only take two values, either "Yes" or "No", I'd prefer to use a radio button:

```
<!-- Active Radio Button-->
<div class="form-outline mb-3" id="activeRadioButton">
   <label class="form-label">Make User Active?</label>
   <div class="activeUser">
      <input type="radio" id="activeYes" name="active" value="Yes">
      <label for="activeYes" class="form-label">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="activeNo" name="active" value="No">
      <label for="activeNo" class="form-label">No</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

But I can't figure how to "set" the appropriate button based on the value passed in via the route. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to control the `checked` attribute of the input type=radio:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#attr-checked

To make it possible you may use an expression like this on the input radio expecting the value `Yes`:

```
<%= active === 'Yes' ? 'checked' : '' %>
```

And an expression like this for on the input radio expecting the value `No`:

```
<%= active === 'No' ? 'checked' : '' %>
```

This is the whole block:

```
<div class="form-outline mb-3" id="activeRadioButton">
   <label class="form-label">Make User Active?</label>
   <div class="activeUser">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="activeYes"
        name="active"
        value="Yes"
        <%= active === 'Yes' ? 'checked' : '' %>
      >
      <label for="activeYes" class="form-label">Yes</label>
      
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="activeNo"
        name="active"
        value="No"
        <%= active === 'No' ? 'checked' : '' %>
      <label for="activeNo" class="form-label">No</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is a live snippet with static html showing the `checked` behaviour on two groups of radio buttons:

```html
<div>
  <input
    type="radio"
    id="activeYes"
    name="active"
    value="Yes">

  <input
    type="radio"
    id="activeNo"
    name="active"
    value="No"
    checked>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <input
    type="radio"
    id="activeYes2"
    name="active2"
    value="Yes"
    checked>

  <input
    type="radio"
    id="activeNo2"
    name="active2"
    value="No">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Diego. I did happen to read the docs. and the same link that you posted, but I wasn't even close to joining the dots.